# Is a SQL Injection possible in this code?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

### Introduction

I have taken over maintenance of a really messy PHP page, which is a booking platform for holiday apartments, but this isn't important. The code was originally done by a designer (not a coder) and it's really bad. Passing boolean variables by "true" and "false" strings is one of the minor WTFs. I want to convince the owner of the page, to give me the time (and money, of course) to clean it up the code (or rewrite it).

Apparently original "developer" had never heard of SQL-injection because he's using POST and GET variables directly in his SQL statements. To convince the owner I want to shock him a littel by logging in as admin without using his password.

### tl;dr (or: The actual question)

This statement (where $p_username is a POST variable which contains the content of the "Username" input field):

```
"SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '$p_username'"
```

The returned string (which is an unsalted MD5-Hash of the password that was stored in the database) is then compared against the (also hashed) string which was entered into the "Password" field and if both strings match the user is logged in as the entered user. Is it possible to put something into the username field to  log in as "fake" admin?

**Note:** DB Server is MySQL, PHP is in Version 5 and `magic_quotes` is enabled.

Comment: @meagar he can't. even in there was injection possibility.  mysql driver ddoesn't support multiple queries. That stupid comic is inapplicable here

Comment: PHP 6 has removed magic quotes so the program cannot be upgraded to a newer PHP version without replacing magic quotes with proper SQL escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Col. Shrapnel, `magic_quotes` does make it impossible, unless you are running under some [very special circumstances](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).

However, if what you say is true, it's quite likely that the original developer didn't know much about magic_quotes, so it's likely he messed up if he ever stored the GET/POST/COOKIE values anywhere else except SQL statements. In short, look for places where `'` and `"` would be legal, and check if they don't get messed up.

Also - did he know about `htmlspecialchars()`, or is HTML/Javascript injection still possible? :)

Comment: Of course there is no kind of escaping done. And there is a public guest book so you could put whatever code you want on the site. Which I will use to steal the (completely unprotected) Session-ID from an admin user. This was my backup plan ;)

Answer (score 0):

With magic quotes enabled it would be impossible.

Comment: It ISN'T impossible. magic quotes doesn't magically stop SQL Injection.

Comment: Well, of course there can be other kinds of injections, but in terms of escaping strings it's pretty safe.

Comment: @cyberkiwi yes, we are. so, we're all using utf8. I wonder how many people want to speak on the topic having no experience nor knowledge but a few stupid articles on their side only.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the full query and the password check is done on the PHP side, you won't be able to login as admin (even if magic_quotes is turned off), because you would still have to match the password hash.

Comment: Not strictly true - if you can manage to get a quote injected, that query becomes toast. Consider something like this query

SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = 'unlikely' union all select char(102,111,111); - this allows use to force the 'password' result to be a string of our choosing, which we would select to match the password we transmit.

Comment: Have expanded on that in an answer, as it's an interesting technique.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

There are multiple attack vectors with `addslashes()`.  The first one I chose below was based on the article previously linked in an answer that quoted it to support the ***opposite*** claim.  At least another one is with overlong strings using no less than the UTF-8 encoding.

http://www.erich-kachel.de/?tag=addslashes

A similar technique as the below could be constructed.  The long and short is, the MySQL team has seen fit to retire `magic_quotes` and also strongly advised against pretending addslashes() is a real form of protection.  **Maybe, you know, the MySQL team would know better?**  For what its worth, mysql_real_escape_string has some edge case vulnerabilities as well, but since it is MySQL-specific instead of just PHP-specific, it does go one step further.  A better solution would be to use query parameters.

#### Original answer follows

Yes it is possible to log in as admin. Not in one go, but two passes will do it.

Ref - http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string
(Yes this is the same link from another answer, but instead, my interpretation is that it IS commonly possible on any multibyte character set except utf8)

You have not stated if you system is multi-byte, but since the question is open, I will assume it is.

```
$p_username = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27) . ';' .
    "update user set password='password', '.
    "username='" . chr(0xbf) . "' where username='admin' /*';

"SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '$p_username'"
```

I have changed the user name AND password of the "admin" user

> This type of attack is possible with any character encoding where there is a valid multi-byte character that ends in 0x5c

Comment: This was my point, I have no clue why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: @van you **cannot** use CHAR() or HEX() functions to get around magic_quotes

Comment: he is using mysql. so, your ingenious code will stop at `';'`. What a pity.

Comment: @Col - did you know that there are **only** 12 other users (>1000 rep) that have a higher downvote:upvote ratio than you? Congratulations.  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/92552/

Comment: @Vanwaril nope, your point is completely different. This guy bets on the vanishingly small chance that this ancient system is using some extremely rare encoding.

Comment: @cyberkiwi that's because others too greedy to give away they'r precious rep points lol :)

Comment: @Col - read up on edited answer. BTW, there are plenty of systems that use multi-byte without using utf8. You know, like maybe the 1/5th of the world that use CJK?

Comment: @Col - and where does he say that the `driver used is mysql`? I'm sure we know MySQL is the back end. But there are MySQL drivers that will take `statement batches`, you know

Comment: okay-okay, go assume that in this ancient app he's using mysqli_musli_query, lol.

Comment: To let you know, if this scenario was ever possible, almost every system in the world which uses MRES to escape strings would become vulnerable, as none ever set client's encoding.

Comment: LOL. I don't need to read these stupid rants. I am writing articles myself. And to let you know, mres alone is not sufficient. unless you set client encoding explicitly, your mres acts exactly the same way as addslashes :)

Comment: @col - You've gone from saying that `magic_quotes` is bulletproof for the question to `vulnerability(mres) = vulnerability(addslashes) = vulnerability(magic_quotes)`. None of them is enough. You're tripping over yourself. Please pick yourself off the floor on your way out. FWIW, I will agree `mysql_real_escape_string` **is** vulnerable, but it is way better than `addslashes()`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, getting the single quote past magic quotes is tricky, but if it could be done, the query is toast. Consider if we could inject the following:

```
SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = 'unlikely' 
UNION ALL SELECT CHAR(102,111,111); #'
```

This will return the string 'foo' to PHP as the password, so all we need to do is ensure our form sends our injection for $username, and 'foo' for the $password.

Comment: I really LOVE that `"Consider if we could"`! Consider if we could not?

Comment: True, but we haven't been provided with that information -  I was just illustrating an attack on the provided query. Given it was coded by an amateur, the login may well be an 'all or nothing' administrative tool. As I've seen this particular attack in the wild, I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: He weren't asked for the injection technique, he's just curious if it's ever possible

Answer (score -2):

I think It's important to validate all input variables and escape all special characters, even if magic_quotes is enabled.

To be sure, you can test your code with sqlmap.